# Kafka multiple topic consume

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, wildcard, kafka-consumer-api

```
   consumer.subscribe(Pattern.compile(".*"),new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> clctn) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> clctn) {
            }            
        });
```

How to consume all topics with regex in apache/kafka?
I tried above code, but it didn't work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained _how_ it didn't work. What did you _expect_ to happen, and what _actually_ happened?

Comment: I want to see logs for all topics. For example, if I write Pattern.compile("abc_log") instead of Pattern.compile(".*"), I can see logs about abc_log. But I want to see all logs related to all topics.

Answer (score 3):

For regex use the following signature

```
KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Pattern pattern, ConsumerRebalanceListener listener)
```

E.g. the following code snippet enables the consumer to listen to all topics with prefix `my_topics_`

```
ConsumerRebalanceListener listener = new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> arg0) {
    // Don't need it now.
  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> arg0) {
    // Don't need it now.
  }
};

pattern = Pattern.compile("my_topics_.*");
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(pattern, listener);
```

Comment: Will this also detect the creation of any new topic at runtime?

Comment: Yes, it will. As long as it's matching the pattern.